# How to prevent user idle in PHP?

Tags: php

I am creating a website that used by user to input their data. User must login to input.

The problem is the server seems to set an idle times. So, if user is idle for x minutes, they're become inactive. That means all of their input is not saved in database while showing success message.

I have no access to the server for setting some configuration. So, how do I make users act as if they are not idle before submitting their forms?

User may idle for more than 30 minutes while the server seems set idle tome for 15minutes

Edit: (If user suceesfully login this script set the sessions)

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(  'id_user'    => $row->id_user,
                        'username'   => $row->username,
                        'level'      => $row->level,
                        'nip'        => $row->nip,
                        'bagian'     => $row->id_bagian,
                        'log_status' => $row->log_status,
                        'validated'  => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);


        return true;
    };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: @catcon where can I put the session time out in my current script?

Comment: I would put at the top of the script, it would check if the user inactive duration before performing any farther action